# docker-engine runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-14.04, init

I am trying to install Docker on a virtual instance of Ubuntu 14.04 from a service provider that may have modified some of the default underlying init system or filesystem.

When trying to do an apt-get install of the latest docker-engine, I get these errors below. Any ideas what I could try?

```
My installation steps:

sudo apt-get install --yes apt-transport-https ca-certificates
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D

echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

sudo apt-get update

apt-cache policy docker-engine

sudo apt-get install --yes linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual

The one giving errors is this one:

125 dnanexus@job-F0QpJ700vBp11ffQk1b9ppYj:~⟫ sudo apt-get install --yes docker-engine                                                                                                                                                                                        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
docker-engine is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up docker-engine (1.12.3-0~trusty) ...
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
mount: block device cgroup is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device cgroup read-only
mount: block device cgroup is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device cgroup read-only
mount: block device cgroup is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device cgroup read-only
mount: block device cgroup is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device cgroup read-only
mount: block device cgroup is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device cgroup read-only
mount: block device cgroup is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device cgroup read-only
mount: block device cgroup is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device cgroup read-only
mount: block device cgroup is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device cgroup read-only
mount: block device cgroup is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device cgroup read-only
/etc/init.d/docker: 96: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package docker-engine (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.12) ...
grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/dev/mapper/md0-crypt2'.
grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/dev/mapper/md0-crypt2'.
grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/dev/mapper/md0-crypt2'.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/dev/mapper/md0-crypt2'.
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up cgroup-lite (1.9) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/cgroup-lite not found.
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package cgroup-lite (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-engine
 grub-pc
 cgroup-lite
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The cgroup (control groups) are an intrinsic part of how containers are managed on linux system, so it's seems you don't have permission there. Either you don't have root, or they've been locked down somehow.